# List of all theme customizer control types?

Tags: php, theme-development, functions, customization

I have been looking through the theme customization API documentation and google to simply find out the names of the control types already built in to the theme customizer.

More specifically I am looking for what the name is of a simple button. I have tried using the type button and input and I am getting nowhere making geusses. So instead of creating a custom control I am sure their has to be a plain old button but I can't find what it is called. So if anyone knows what it is called or can point me to a list with the control types and their names I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look in the source:
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-control.php

Basic control types:

- text
- checkbox
- radio
- select
- dropdown-pages

Also some advanced control types ([as-described by Otto](http://ottopress.com/2012/how-to-leverage-the-theme-customizer-in-your-own-themes/)):

- WP_Customize_Color_Control - extends the built in WP_Customize_Control class. It adds the color wheel jazz to places where color selection is needed.
- WP_Customize_Upload_Control – This gives you an upload box, for allowing file uploads. However, you probably won’t use this directly, you’ll extend it for other things… like:
- WP_Customize_Image_Control – This gives the image picker and the uploader box. It extends the upload controller. You can see it in action on the custom background piece, where a user can upload a new file to be the background image.
- WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control – Because of the resizing action of the header piece, it needs a bit of special handling and display, so the WP_Customize_Header_Image_Control extends the WP_Customize_Image_Control to add that functionality. You can see it in action on the custom header piece, where a user can upload a new file to be the header image.

Also:

- WP_Customize_Background_Image_Control

If you need more than that, you'll have to define your own, custom control.

Comment: Thank you, your post definitely made sure I didn't continue searching google for another hour. I ended up creating a custom control for the button.

Answer (score 2):

Supported control types are `text`, `checkbox`, `radio`, `select`, `textarea`, `dropdown-pages`, `email`, `url`, `number`, `hidden`, and `date`.

> reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Customize_Manager/add_control